# T-SQL Check if list has values, select and Insert into Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm quite new to T-SQL and currently struggling with an insert statement in my stored procedure: I use as a parameter in the stored procedure a list of ids of type INT.

If the list is NOT empty, I want to store the ids into the table Delivery.

To pass the list of ids, i use a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE tIdList AS TABLE 
(
    ID INT NULL
);
GO
```

Maybe you know a better way to pass a list of ids into a stored procedure?

However, my procedure looks as follows:

```
-- parameter
@DeliveryModelIds tIdList READONLY

...
DECLARE @StoreId INT = 1;

-- Delivery
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @DeliveryModelIds)
    INSERT [MyDB].[Delivery] ([DeliveryModelId], [StoreId])
    OUTPUT inserted.DeliveryId
        SELECT ID FROM @DeliveryModelIds;
```

If the list has values, I want to store the values into the DB as well as the StoreId which is always 1.

If I insert the DeliveryIds 3,7,5 The result in table Delivery should look like this:

DeliveryId | StoreId | DeliveryModelId
1...............| 1...........| 3
2...............| 1...........| 7
3...............| 1...........| 5

Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue?

THANKS !

Comment: The error message should already be giving you a clue - you name two columns after the table name in `INSERT` but then give it a `SELECT` that only selects one value. Not sure that the `OUTPUT` clause is meant to be doing here at the moment. (And yes, you've picked the right way of sending in multiple values to the procedure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `@StoreId` to your `select` for your `insert`.

```
...
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @DeliveryModelIds)
    INSERT [MyDB].[Delivery] ([DeliveryModelId], [StoreId])
    OUTPUT inserted.DeliveryId
        SELECT ID, @StoreId FROM @DeliveryModelIds;
```

Additionally, if you only want to insert `DeliveryModelId` that do not currently exist in the target table, you can use `not exists()` in the `where` clause like so:

```
...
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @DeliveryModelIds)
    INSERT [MyDB].[Delivery] ([DeliveryModelId], [StoreId])
    OUTPUT inserted.DeliveryId
        SELECT dmi.ID, @StoreId 
        FROM @DeliveryModelIds dmi
        where not exists (
          select 1
          from MyDb.Delivery i
          where i.StoreId = @StoreId
            and i.DeliveryModeId = dmi.ID
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `INSERT` statement to:

```
INSERT [MyDB].[Delivery] ([DeliveryModelId], [StoreId])
    OUTPUT inserted.DeliveryId
        SELECT ID, 1 FROM @DeliveryModelIds;
```

So you are also selecting a literal, `1`, along with `ID` field.